# FFmpeg hardsubbing using force_style, fontname fontsdir, subtitles, and ass filter

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -i "/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/ICSM dance.mkv" -c:s copy -q:s 0 -c:a copy -c:d copy -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 0 -map_metadata 0 -vf "scale=1920:-1,colorspace=all=bt2020,ass=/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/ICSM dance.ass:fontsdir=/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf" -bufsize 960M -maxrate 480M -r:v 30 -r:a 30 -t 30 -movflags +write_colr "/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/30s samples.ts"
```

This is the input and output says..

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/ICSM dance.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-12-16T20:39:56.000000Z
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:03:30.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 218 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 256x144, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.009000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.071000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] libass API version: 0x1501000
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] libass source: tarball: 0.15.1
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.10 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 2.8.1 (COMPLEX)
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] Using font provider fontconfig
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] Added subtitle file: '/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/ICSM dance.ass' (2 styles, 58 events)
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] Neither PlayResX nor PlayResY defined. Assuming 384x288
Output #0, mpegts, to '/storage/0040-18A0/Music Videos on YouTube/TO be synced/30s samples.ts':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-12-16T20:39:56.000000Z
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/bt2020-10, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 90k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.009000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 480000000/0/200000 buffer size: 960000000 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      DURATION        : 00:03:30.071000000
```

Can anyone help me how to use system fonts on ffmpeg Termux? Whatever I try is only giving me DroidSansFallback. Here is another one that ffmpeg says....

```
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] fontselect: ("/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf", 400, 0) -> /system/fonts/Lohit-Punjabi.ttf, 0, Lohit-Punjabi
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] fontselect: (DroidSansChinese, 400, 0) -> /system/fonts/Lohit-Punjabi.ttf, 0, Lohit-Punjabi
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] Glyph 0x41 not found, selecting one more font for (DroidSansChinese, 16, 400)
[Parsed_ass_2 @ 0xa51dd240] fontselect: (DroidSansChinese, 400, 0) -> /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf, 0, DroidSansFallback
```

This the last ffmpeg says...

```
frame=  899 fps=1.7 q=0.0 Lsize=   25350kB time=00:00:29.97 bitrate=6927.5kbits/s speed=0.0563x
video:24095kB audio:469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.197927%
```

Thanks in advance for those who can help me!

Comment: How is Ubuntu involved?

Comment: Because I installed ffmpeg on Ubuntu. "apt install ffmpeg"

Comment: Please show the **complete** output from ffmpeg.

Comment: Recheck the subtitles for (1) correct encoding probably have to be utf8 and (2) unsupported glyph (char). Try open it in text editor.

Comment: @user.dz yes thanks, ive posted my own answer above so other users will understands too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing i found out that the `FontName` was `Droid Sans` and not the actual font location. Then `fontsdir` needs the folder location of our font file and not the actual font file too

The commands for hardsubbing will be:

> -vf "subtitles=(srt location):fontsdir=(folder location of font):force_style='FontName=Droid Sans,Fontsize=12'"

My example:

```
-vf "subtitles=/storage/emulated/0/0.srt:fontsdir=/storage/emulated/0/fonts/:force_style='FontName=Droid Sans,Fontsize=12'"
```

To know your `Fontname`, you can go online at [fontdrop.info](https://fontdrop.info) using any browser then upload your font file there or if you are using windows, hover the mouse to your font file then the name will appear below it

For `ass` filter, edit your ass file using any text editor then replace the fontname and fontsize there. You dont need to input the `force_style` option above, just use `fontsdir` and replace `-vf subtitles` to `-vf ass`

Like this:

```
-vf "ass=/storage/emulated/0/0.ass:fontsdir=/storage/emulated/0/fonts/"
```

**This is for termux android, windows cmd, or even mac**. And i had to use double quotation because of some minor issues.

Comment: Probably when a font missing it tried to replace it with another font which doesn't cover that  glyph. This leads to get such error message not from root cause.

Comment: @user.dz done merging comments, and yes when the font file has missing glyphs, the software will find another matching font that contains the missing glyphs then use it for hardsubbing.